# jQuery - Keeping a js array and list of DOM objects in sync?

Tags: jquery, dom

Let's say I have an array of objects

`[{href: 'some_uri', 'class': 'this-css-class'}, {href: 'another_uri', 'class': 'that-css-class'}]`

I now want to map that to a html list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="this-css-class"><a href="some_uri">some_uri</a></li>
  <li class="that-css-class"><a href="another_uri">another_uri</a></li>
</ul>
```

Assume I add another object to my array, I want to have a new `<li>` added to the list as well. Conversely, when I `$('.that-css-class').remove()` one of the list items, I want it to be gone in the array as well.

I would like to keep it in jQuery, as I don't want to introduce another framework to the project.

Help greatly appreciated, this has been doing my head in.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)? It uses the MVVM pattern to perform DOM model binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ? : http://jsfiddle.net/RZPNG/4/

```
var datas = [
    {href: 'some_uri', 'class': 'this-css-class'}, 
    {href: 'another_uri', 'class': 'that-css-class'}
],
  ul = $('ul');

$.each(datas, function(key, value) { // initialize list
    createElement(value);
});

function createElement(elem) {
    ul.append($('<li class=' + elem.class + '><a href="' + elem.href + '">' + elem.href + '</a></li>'));
}

function addElement(elem) {
    datas.push(elem);
    createElement(elem);
}

function removeElement(i) {
    datas.splice(i, 1);
    $(ul.find('li').get(i)).remove();
}

addElement({href: 'foo', 'class': 'bar'});
removeElement(1);
```

Selector way :

```
var datas = [
    {href: 'some_uri', 'class': 'this-css-class'}, 
    {href: 'another_uri', 'class': 'that-css-class'}
],
  ul = $('ul');

$.each(datas, function(key, value) { // initialize list
    createElement(value);
});

function createElement(elem) {
    ul.append($('<li class=' + elem.class + '><a href="' + elem.href + '">' + elem.href + '</a></li>'));
}

function addElement(elem) {
    datas.push(elem);
    createElement(elem);
}

function removeElement(selector) {
    datas.splice(findElement(selector), 1);
    $(ul.find('li.' + selector)).remove();
}

function findElement(selector) {
    for (var i in datas) {
        if (datas[i].class === selector) {
           return i;   
        }
    }                
}

addElement({href: 'foo', 'class': 'bar'});
removeElement('that-css-class');
```

Comment: I've based the remove function on the array index, but you could easily adapt that to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. That would have been my approach as well, I didnt like the fact though, that I have to update both (array and ul) when adding/deleting elements. I thought maybe there is a more elegant way. Unfortunately jQuery doesnt support straight up data-binding like other frameworks would (I guess it also isn't supposed to).

Comment: Yes i understand your point. And you are right, jQuery core don't offer heavy data-binding options (and don't intend to). I suspect that there is some plugins that could do that in a certain way. @amitamb backbone.js is a very good suggestion to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your exact use case is but keeping your data and view(i.e. DOM) in sync is handled very well by [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#)

You can see following example app to see how Model, Collection and View are used to keep JSON data stored in localStorage in sync with what is displayed to user through DOM

[Demo](http://localtodos.com/) and [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)

But this is just a part of functionality provided by backbone.js which can be embedded in a single library as you are suggesting. I don't know of any such library though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know of backbone.js but I wanted to keep it to jQuery as I dont want to introduce another framework. Maybe should have stated more explicitly in my question.